# Javascript inside a Wordpress loop

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

I am trying to run Javascript inside my Wordpress loop and it won't recognise the PHP Variables. I want it so when one box is clicked it will show hidden content then when another box or that box is clicked again it should hide all the content.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#show").on("click", function(e) {


        var target = $(this).attr("href");
        $(target).slideToggle("fast");
        $("<?php echo $name; ?>").not(target).hide();
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

That is inside a foreach loop of each custom post type label. Anyone have any advice? Thanks.

Comment: Can you post the entire loop? Is jQuery called before this code? Any errors?

Answer (score 0):

maybe this will work for you.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#on").click(function(){
        $("#area you want to hide/show").toggle();
    });

});
</script>
```

Comment: Sort of worked but it is toggling them all when I click the first box in the wordpress loop.

Comment: so give the part that you want to get toggled a specific id or class

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php  $args = array( 'public' => true,'_builtin' => false );
$output = 'names';
$i = 0;
$operator = 'and';
$post_types = get_post_types( $args, $output, $operator );
foreach ( $post_types  as $post_type ) {
    $link = get_post_type_object($post_type);
    $name = $link->label;
    $singular = $link->labels->singular_name;
    $i++;
    ?>

<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#show").click(function(){
        $(".<?php echo $post_type; ?>").toggle();
    });

});


</script>


    <?php if($i % (4 + 1) == 0 || $i == 1) {?>
<ul class="col-1-1">
   <li class="col-1-4" >
     <div class="backgroundimage" id="show" style="background-image: url('<?php the_field($post_type,'option'); ?>'); background-size: 100%;">

         <h2 class="heading"><?php echo $singular; ?> </h2>

     </div>
     <div class="<?php echo $post_type; ?> col-1-1" style="display: none;">

                   <?php } else { ?>
                     <li class="col-1-4" >
                       <div class="backgroundimage" id="<?php echo $singular;  ?>" style="background-image: url('<?php the_field($post_type,'option') ?>'); background-size: 100%;">

                           <h2 class="heading"><?php echo $singular;  ?> </h2>

                       </div>
                       <div class="<?php echo $post_type; ?> col-1-1" style="display: none;">

<?php } ?>





<?php
// The Query
$args = array(
'post_type' => $post_type,
);
$wp_query = new WP_Query( $args );


$count = 0;
?>

<?php if ( $wp_query->have_posts() ) : ?>

<!-- pagination here -->

<!-- the loop -->
<?php while ( $wp_query->have_posts() ) : $wp_query->the_post(); ?>

  <?php $count++;
   ?>

  <?php if($count == 1){ ?>
    <div class="col-1-2 resource " >
      <div class="interior" style="background-image: url('http://placehold.it/640x500');">
      <div class="">
        <div class="interiorbox">
        <h3 class="col-10-12"><?php the_title(); ?> </h3>
        <p class="number col-2-12"><?php echo $count ?></p>
        <p class="col-1-1">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore</p>
        <p class="col-1-1"><a href="abduzeedo.com">abduzeedo.com</a></p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <?php } elseif ($count >= 4) { ?>


      <?php } else { ?>
      <div class="col-1-4 resource " >
        <div class="interior" style="background-image: url('http://placehold.it/320x500');">
        <div class="">
          <div class="interiorbox">
          <h3 class="col-10-12"><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
          <p class="number col-2-12"><?php echo $count ?></p>
          <p class="col-1-1">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore</p>
          <p class="col-1-1"><a href="abduzeedo.com">abduzeedo.com</a></p>
        </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      </div>
<?php }  ?>




<!-- post -->

<?php endwhile; ?>
<!-- end of the loop -->

<!-- pagination here -->
<?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>



<?php else : ?>
<p><?php _e( 'Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.' ); ?></p>
<?php endif; ?>


<?php if( $i % 4 == 0 ) { ?>


</div>
</li>
</ul>

<?php } else { ?>


</div>
</li>
  <?php } ?>

<?php
}?>
```

It is choas but it makes sense to me. It is giving me lines of 4 ul's then starts a new one.

Comment: jquery is being called as well. It works to a point where it toggles them all when I click the first child. I need it to do it individually for each post type

Comment: You're outputting the div with id `show` each time in your foreach loop, so your click event is getting attached to all of these divs. Identify each uniquely as a starting point.

Comment: I have given each one a unique id but they can all be displayed at once I just want one showing at a time. Is that a possibility?

Comment: You'll need to update your question with your most recent code if you're looking for help debugging it.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php  $args = array( 'public' => true,'_builtin' => false );
$output = 'names';
$i = 0;
$operator = 'and';
$post_types = get_post_types( $args, $output, $operator );
foreach ( $post_types  as $post_type ) {
    $link = get_post_type_object($post_type);
    $name = $link->label;
    $singular = $link->labels->singular_name;
    $i++;
    ?>

<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#<?php echo $post_type;?>s").click(function(){
       $(".<?php echo $post_type; ?>").toggle();
 });

});

</script>

    <?php if($i % (4 + 1) == 0 || $i == 1) {?>
<ul class="col-1-1">
   <li class="col-1-4" >
     <div class="backgroundimage" id="<?php echo $post_type;?>s" style="background-image: url('<?php the_field($post_type,'option'); ?>'); background-size: 100%;">

         <h2 class="heading"><?php echo $singular; ?> </h2>

     </div>
     <div class="<?php echo $post_type; ?> col-1-1" style="display: none;">

                   <?php } else { ?>
                     <li class="col-1-4" >
                       <div class="backgroundimage" id="<?php echo $post_type;?>s" style="background-image: url('<?php the_field($post_type,'option') ?>'); background-size: 100%;">

                           <h2 class="heading"><?php echo $singular;  ?> </h2>

                       </div>
                       <div class="<?php echo $post_type; ?> col-1-1" style="display: none;">

<?php } ?>





<?php
// The Query
$args = array(
'post_type' => $post_type,
);
$wp_query = new WP_Query( $args );


$count = 0;
?>

<?php if ( $wp_query->have_posts() ) : ?>

<!-- pagination here -->

<!-- the loop -->
<?php while ( $wp_query->have_posts() ) : $wp_query->the_post(); ?>

  <?php $count++;
   ?>

  <?php if($count == 1){ ?>
    <div class="col-1-2 resource " >
      <div class="interior" style="background-image: url('http://placehold.it/640x500');">
      <div class="">
        <div class="interiorbox">
        <h3 class="col-10-12"><?php the_title(); ?> </h3>
        <p class="number col-2-12"><?php echo $count ?></p>
        <p class="col-1-1">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore</p>
        <p class="col-1-1"><a href="abduzeedo.com">abduzeedo.com</a></p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <?php } elseif ($count >= 4) { ?>


      <?php } else { ?>
      <div class="col-1-4 resource " >
        <div class="interior" style="background-image: url('http://placehold.it/320x500');">
        <div class="">
          <div class="interiorbox">
          <h3 class="col-10-12"><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
          <p class="number col-2-12"><?php echo $count ?></p>
          <p class="col-1-1">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore</p>
          <p class="col-1-1"><a href="abduzeedo.com">abduzeedo.com</a></p>
        </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      </div>
<?php }  ?>




<!-- post -->

<?php endwhile; ?>
<!-- end of the loop -->

<!-- pagination here -->
<?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>



<?php else : ?>
<p><?php _e( 'Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.' ); ?></p>
<?php endif; ?>


<?php if( $i % 4 == 0 ) { ?>


</div>
</li>
</ul>

<?php } else { ?>


</div>
</li>
  <?php } ?>

<?php
}?>
```

Is there a way to display only 1 at a time?